# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'methods')

Tags: anchor, javascript, anchor-test

I am running test for the default program which comes with anchor setup. However, I keep getting the above error.

the steps I followed were

1. anchor init (project-name)
2. start solana-test-validator
3. anchor build -> anchor deploy
4. update program ids on both anchor.toml and lib.rs
5. anchor build -> anchor deploy
   then run the test

default lib.rs with hello world

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("8455D3DCzghmDygw2STMttPo9sB6SBHUavNP7eHbqNiu");

#[program]
pub mod hello_world {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Hello, world!");
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize {}
```

test file

```
it("Is initialized!", async () => {
// Add your test here.
    const tx = await program.methods.initialize().rpc();
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
  });
```

Error

```
   Is initialized!:
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'methods')
```

Comment: please provide the code and example

Comment: Hace you built the program using `anchor build` first? It may be because your IDL (and thus, types) aren't built

Comment: Please provide more information to make it easier for others to provide an appropriate answer. As your question is currently written, it's difficult to give you a correct answer. A code snippet would be pretty helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your test can't find the Program types for your IDL.
If the test file you have supplied in your question is indeed everything in the file, a full test file would likely look like:

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { Program } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { Hello } from "../target/types/hello";

describe("hello", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());

  const program = anchor.workspace.Hello as Program<Hello>;

  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    // Add your test here.
    const tx = await program.methods.initialize().rpc();
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
  });
});
```

As you can see in the snippet I've posted, it imports the program types in this line:
`import { Hello } from "../target/types/hello";`